# SQLite Connection for a database in Windows Phone application

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am having a SQLite database database.sqlite. I have used the Build Action = Content and Copy to Output Directory, if newer options.

I am using the SQLite DB in a Windows Phone 8 Application. I have used SQLite For WP8 extension, SQLite-NET and SQLite-NET-WP8 projects in GitHub.

I am using the following statements to connect:

`var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.sqlite;Version=3")` to connect to the database.

I am getting a cryptic error - No such table found.

It looks like it is a connectivity issue. Any pointers on how to set up the connection to a SQLite database in Windows phone 8 App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good tutorial about using SQL Lite [found here...](http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/01/29/SQLite-in-Windows-Phone-8.aspx) hope it helps!